# Getting data from a database in a datetimelocal form element on Zend framework2

Tags: php, datetime, zend-framework2, formatting

I've a form set up using Zend Framework 2 with an element type `'DateTimeLocal'`

When I add a new record using the form all works well.

When I edit a record the form appears to fill out correctly: I've formatted the data to pass to the form using:

`$this->startDate  = (!empty($data['startDate'])) ? date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",strtotime($data['startDate'])) : null;`

and in the view add using:

`echo $this->formRow($form->get('startDate'));`

However when I go to submit the form having made edits, I get the message 'The input does not appear to be a valid date'. Using the chrome I re-enter the date, and it appears identical to what was pre-filled, but then submits fine.

html source rendered by zendframework is:
`<label><span>Start Date</span><input type="datetime" name="startDate" value="2014-12-21T00&#x3A;00&#x3A;00"></label>`

I'd have thought this was a common action but seam to be struggling to find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually stumbled across https://stackoverflow.com/a/32003481/1836257

My date format was incorrect. I should have used
`$this->startDate  = (!empty($data['startDate'])) ? date("Y-m-d\TH:i",strtotime($data['startDate'])) : null;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure and a bit surprised by this issue. But the value `2014-12-21T00&#x3A;00&#x3A;00` seems to be an html encoded version of `2014-12-21T00:00:00` and it might be that submitting this is resulting in an invalid response.

I don't know exactly how this value got there, but you should try to get a not encoded value set for `startDate`, then your form might work as expected.